# How many phase-shifted samples are required to eliminate the harmonics of a complex wave?

Tags: fourier-transform, signal-processing

Let $w$ be a complex periodic wave with an infinite number of harmonics. What is the required number of samples $N$, phase-shifted incrementally by equal steps of $2\pi/N$, in order to eliminate harmonics up to the $j$th order through phase-cancelation?

My intuition says I would need $lcm(1, 2, 3, ..., j)*2$ samples so that there is a corresponding antiphase for all frequencies at each phase-shift increment. For instance, if I wanted to eliminate harmonics up to the 2nd order, I would need 4 samples with $\pi/2$ phase-shift increments. For the fundamental frequency, the phase-shifted pairs at increments [$0 - \pi$] and [$\pi/2 - 3\pi/2$] would be in antiphase relationship and cancel each other. Likewise, the second harmonic would be eliminated by the phase-cancelation of pairs at [$0 - \pi/2$] and [$\pi - 3\pi/2$] increments.

I was wondering if there is a better way that can minimize $N$. I'm not from a math-heavy background so I would appreciate laymen explanations.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is a "sample"? Is it a pure frequency at some amplitude and phase shift -- a sinusoidal wave? Or something else?

Comment: @david-k by sample I mean phase shifted versions of a waveform that is sum of a fundamental frequency *f* and its harmonics. So the sample itself is not a sine wave. But when I talk about phase or phase shift, I mean the phase of the fundamental frequency.

Comment: If you're not allowed to phase-shift the harmonics then you'll never be able to cancel them in general. If you phase-shift all harmonics together with the fundamental then you just need $j$ samples to cancel $j$ harmonics. Can you either give a more complete definition or give us a link to a place where this concept is defined? This information should be edited into the question.